# Unable to change the security group of a network interface

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to delete a security group, `sg-d578d9ab`, in my AWS account.

I got the following message when trying to delete it.

> These security groups are associated with one or more network
>   interfaces. Delete the network interfaces, or associate them with
>   different security groups. View your network interfaces.

[image]

In order to solve the problem, I opened the *Network Interfaces* page to see which network interface is using `sg-d578d9ab`.

It turns out there's 1 network interface that's using the security group.

Then I use *Change Security Groups* option to dissociate the security group from the network interface.

Then I got a message saying

> You do not have permission to access the specified resource.

Why can't I change the security group of the network interface?

My AWS account has `AdministratorAccess` permission.

The `Attachment owner` and `Owner ID` properties of the network interface are `amazon-rds`. This seems to be the reason I can't change its security group.

Does this mean that the network interface is created when someone else sets up an AWS RDS?

Comment: is this a privatelink interface created by RDS?

Comment: @RandallHunt, how do I know if it is a privatelink interface created by RDS?

Comment: I had the same issue, This helped me fix it: https://medium.com/theloudcloud/problems-detaching-enis-2aa789dad693

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The security group, `sg-d578d9ab`, is used by one of my RDS instances.

After dissociating the RDS instance and the security group. I'm able to delete the security group.

Answer (score 2):

Saw the same error, but from a VPC endpoint. After dissociating the VPC endpoint from the security group, I was able to delete the security group.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the other answers, it is quite common to have this problem because the Security Group is blocking the Network interface from been changed.

In my case, I had to remove the SG from a load balancer first, so its interface would be allowed to be changed or delete.

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html):

> If you try to detach a network interface that is attached to a
> resource from another service, such as an Elastic Load Balancing load
> balancer, a Lambda function, a WorkSpace, or a NAT gateway, you get an
> error that you do not have permission to access the resource. To find
> which service created the resource attached to a network interface,
> check the description of the network interface. If you delete the
> resource, then its network interface is deleted.